# how do i solve dayNight theme problem in flutter?

Tags: flutter, import, theme-daynight

could u help me out please?? the problem is :

The library 'package:day_night_switch/day_night_switch.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library.
Try migrating the imported...

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the suggestions in https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide to migrate it.

You can firstly download it to local (i.e. make a clone) and then migrate it.